# Query string funciona no Phpmyadmin e não funciona no PHP

Tags: php, mysql, query, mysqli

Tenho a seguinte query que retoma uma data, foi testada no phpmyadmin e no programa HeidiSQL com sucesso:

Query Mysql

```
set @rn:=0,@grp:=0,@prevdate:='';
from 
(select DataEncomenda,
   @rn:=@rn+1 as rownum, 
    @grp:=if(@prevdate=DataEncomenda,@grp,@grp+1) as descGrp, 
    @prevdate:=DataEncomenda as unused 
    from encomendas 
    order by DataEncomenda DESC 
) inR 
where descGrp=2 group by descGrp
```

quando tento utiliza-la no php devolve o erro:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in xxx

O erro retornado pelo banco via php é:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT DataEncomenda FROM ( SELECT DataEncomenda, @rn:=@rn+1 as rownum' at line 2

Código em PHP:

```
$PenultimaData = " 
set @rn:=0,@grp:=0,@prevdate:=''; 
SELECT DataEncomenda
FROM 
(   SELECT DataEncomenda,
    @rn:=@rn+1 as rownum, 
    @grp:=if(@prevdate=DataEncomenda,@grp,@grp+1) as descGrp, 
    @prevdate:=DataEncomenda as unused 
    FROM encomendas 
    ORDER by DataEncomenda DESC 
) inR 
where descGrp=2 group by descGrp";

$Rs = $mysqli->query($PenultimaData);
$Resultado = $Rs->fetch_assoc();

$PenulData = $Resultado['DataEncomenda'];
```

Comment: Tente assim e veja se aparce algum erro, `$mysqli->query($PenultimaData)or die($mysqli->error);`

Comment: O erro que dá é: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT DataEncomenda FROM ( SELECT DataEncomenda, @rn:=@rn+1 as rownum' at line 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método `query()` executa apenas uma 'instrução' SQL por vez, a consulta manda duas delas, a primeira é a definição das variáveis a segunda o select, a delimitação é feita pelo ponto e vírgula.

A maneira mais simples resolver isso é quebrar as instruções (quando possível) e envia-las individualmente.

```
$mysqli->query("set @rn:=0,@grp:=0,@prevdate:='';");

$sql = "SELECT DataEncomenda
FROM 
(   SELECT DataEncomenda,
    @rn:=@rn+1 as rownum, 
    @grp:=if(@prevdate=DataEncomenda,@grp,@grp+1) as descGrp, 
    @prevdate:=DataEncomenda as unused 
    FROM encomendas 
    ORDER by DataEncomenda DESC 
) inR 
where descGrp=2 group by descGrp";

$Rs = $mysqli->query($sql);
$Resultado = $Rs->fetch_assoc();
print_r($Resultado);
```

Outra forma para casos mais complexos é usa [multiple_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) que permite o envio de várias consultas.

```
//envia 3 consultas para o banco
$db->multi_query('set @teste = 2015; select @teste + 1 as ano; select @teste + 1 as ano;') or die($db->error);

do{
    //armazena o resultada consulta
    if($result = $db->store_result()){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){// extrai o resultado do resource
            echo $row['ano'] .'<br>';
        }
    }   
}while($db->more_results() && $db->next_result());
// primeiro verifica se existem mais resultados se sim, 'avança' para o próximo.
```

Comment: Usando a instrução,  mysqli_multi_query?

Comment: @PauloRosa pode usar sim, tem um trabalho adicional logo edito a resposta com um exemplo dela.

Comment: Excelente :) +1

Comment: Caro rray. muito Obrigado. Funcionou. Obrigado por partilhares os teus teus conhecimentos. Dispõe.